# SensorManager.getOrientation()vs. Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION

Tags: android

sry if there are Information which answer my question but I can't find anything to solve my problem.

I try to get the same Information from azimuth,pitch and roll from the "orientationsensor" and
SensorManager.getOrientation() to compare these different ways. I know that  SensorManager.getOrientation()give me values in radians is there a solution to calculate azimuth(0-360),pitch(0- +-180) and roll(+-90) from these radians values.

Thank You Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.toDegrees()` to convert from radians to degrees.